# HBase : What is the default size of Memcache,WAL and BlockCache if i don't configure them?

Tags: hbase

What is the size of memstore and blockcache in hbase. I am new to hbase and I were studying the architecture of hbase at that time I was unable to find the size of those block.

Comment: This might change among different HBase distributions (hdp, cdh..) but check this - https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#config.files. You can always just check the `configurations` tab on the UI when the cluster is running.

Comment: Thanks,in the link default are given,thanks for your answer.